# How do you Javascript charAt() a integer?

Tags: javascript, parsing, integer

I have an array. One of the values in that array `responses[1]` is an integer. This integer can be from 1 to whatever number you want. I need to get the last number in the integer and determine based on that number if I should end the number with 'st', 'nd', 'rd', or 'th'. How do I do that? I tried:

```
var placeEnding;
var placeInt = response[1]; //101
var stringInt = placeInt.toString();
var lastInt = stringInt.charAt(stringInt.length-1);
if (lastInt == '1'){
    placeEnding = 'st';
} else if (lastInt == '2'){
    placeEnding = 'nd';
} else if (lastInt == '3'){
    placeEnding = 'rd';
} else {
    placeEnding = 'th';
}
```

but that did not work. Every time I tried printing `placeEnding` it was always 'th' no matter if it should have been 'st', 'rd', or 'nd'. When I tried printing `placeInt`, `stringInt`, or `lastInt` they all printed as `"` instead of the number. Why is this so? When I print `responses[1]` later on in the script I have no problem getting the right answer.

Comment: response[1] or responses[1]..?

Comment: @Sudhir wow! thanks. That is exactly what was wrong. responses[1].

Comment: Note that your code, like most of the answers below, will turn the numbers 11, 12 and 13 into "11st", "12nd" and "13rd". To handle those cases correctly, you'd also need to check that the second-to-last digit isn't 1. (Also, I can't resist linking to [this related codegolf.SE challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4707/outputting-ordinal-numbers-1st-2nd-3rd), which was posted just a few days after this question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is the last digit, just use the modulus operator:
`123456 % 10 == 6`
No need to bother with string conversions or anything.

Comment: +1 Is probably more efficient than my solution. I updated my answer, but see my warning about decimal points.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
var ends = {
    '1': 'st',
    '2': 'nd',
    '3': 'rd'
}

response[1] += ends[ response[1].toString().split('').pop() ] || 'th';
```

---

As others have pointed out, using modulus 10 is more efficient:

```
response[1] += ends[ parseInt(response[1], 10) % 10 ] || 'th';
```

However, this'll break if the number has a decimal in it. If you think it might, use the previous solution.

Comment: What would you call the ordinal corresponding to, say, `21.173`, anyway?  "Twenty-one-point-one-seven-third"?  "Twenty-first-point-one-seven-three"?  Fortunately, I suspect this is not an issue that comes up very often in practice.

Answer (score 2):

In my rhino console.

```
js> (82434).toString().match(/\d$/)
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way to get lastInt is:

```
 var lastInt = parseInt(stringInt)%10;
switch lastInt {
    case 1:
        placeEnding = 'st';
        break;
    case 2:
        placeEnding = 'nd';
        break;
    case 3:
        placeEnding = 'rd';
        break;
    default:
        placeEnding = 'th';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed I wanted to use the st/nd/rd/th in dates, and just noticed there is an exception between 10 and 20 with the **eleventh**, **twelfth** and so on, so I came to this conclusion:

```
if (n % 10 === 1 && (n % 100) - 1 !== 10) {
    return "st";
} else if (n % 10 === 2 && (n % 100) - 2 !== 10) {
    return "nd";
} else if (n % 10 === 3 && (n % 100) - 3 !== 10) {
    return "rd";
}
return "th";
```